# how to only remove 3 of 5 specific items of an array swift

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode

I have an array

```
var arr = ["car", "car", "bike", "bus", "car", "car", "car"]
```

When I try to filter :

```
var newArr = arr.filter { $0 != "car" }
```

It removes all 5 cars, I only need to remove 3

I want new array to be:

```
["bike", "bus", "car", "car"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply add a counter and check the condition inside your filter predicate:

---

```
var arr = ["car", "car", "bike", "bus", "car", "car", "car"]

var counter = 3
let newArr = arr.filter {
    if counter > 0, $0 == "car" {
        counter -= 1
        return false
    }
    return true
}

print(newArr)
```

---

This will print:

> ["bike", "bus", "car", "car"]

---

If you would like to implement a removeAll(where:) method with the option to limit the number of elements removed you can implement something like:

```
extension RangeReplaceableCollection {
    mutating func removeAll(where predicate: ((Element) -> Bool), limitedTo counter: Int) {
        var counter = counter
        removeAll {
            if counter > 0, predicate($0) {
                counter -= 1
                return true
            }
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

---

Usage:

```
var arr = ["car", "car", "bike", "bus", "car", "car", "car"]
arr.removeAll(where: { $0 == "car"}, limitedTo: 3)
print(arr)  // "["bike", "bus", "car", "car"]\n"
```